# Using an Arch Linux persistent USB on mac

Tags: usb, installation, macbook-pro, persistent, arch-linux

Ok, so i following this guide on the Arch Wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key,
and installed Arch successfully to my 16GB sandisk cruzer. Ive got 3 partitions, root, var, and home. I installed GRUB on the flash drive, and the installation was a success. I have windows installed with bootcamp, and i installed refit to boot from the usb, and a "boot linux from HD" option comes up in refit, but if i press it, it boots windows?